# How to figure out which command line parameters have been set in plac?

Tags: python, argparse

My `Python` script takes configuration values in this order:

1. command line argument (possibility to overwrite user defined values in configuration file)
2. configuration file value (user defined values)
3. default value in source code

I need to figure out which option has been set on the command line in order to determine whether a default value has been set explicitly or not. [plac](https://plac.googlecode.com/hg/doc/plac.html) is [not?] very transparent and I don't see how it's possible. I would like to avoid to parse `sys.argv` because writing a command line parser in order to use a command line parser doesn't seem like a good idea.

I'm using `plac` 0.9.1 on `Ubuntu 15.04`.

Comment: Why do you care if the (default) value comes from the command line or from another place?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I clearified that user defined values are both in the configuration file and can be specified on the command line. If a default value is specified on the command line (e.g. because the user has no idea about the default values) I need to know if I take the value from the config file or not.

Comment: And why not use 3 variables one for the default parameters and one for the command line? You can then check if you have var_command_line_param else use default and affect your interval variable, the one used by your script to do the task...

Comment: I have no idea how to get this information in `plac`, i.e. how to set values of these two or three variables or make `plac` set them for me, please explain! All comes down to a python function for me. Which object do I need to access?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a simple example of your `plac` setup?  I used to know it well, but now know the underlying `argparse` better.

Are you using `plac` to invoke a *function*(s) directly, *e.g*.

```
plac.call(main)
```

Internally `plac` creates an `argparse.ArgumentParser` (actually its own subclass), populates it with arguments derived from a functions signature.  And then calls that function with the values it parsed.

If working with `argparse` directly, you create the parser, populate it, and invoke it with

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

`args` is now a `Namespace` object with attributes named after the arguments.  It can also be converted to a dictionary.

If you go the `argparse` route (possibly still creating the parser with `plac`), you can easily check the attributes in `args`, and compare those values with your defaults, or with the `config` file values.

`IPython` actually populates an `argparse.parser` with arguments derived from config files (default and custom).  This lets you over ride config defaults at several stages - with custom files or with the commandline.

`plac` is supposed to be easier than `argparse`, by integrating parser creation and function calling.  But in your case it may be better to separate those steps.

---

The code for `plac.call` is:

```
def call(obj, arglist=sys.argv[1:], eager=True):
   ...
   cmd, result = parser_from(obj).consume(arglist)
   ...
```

The first part creates a parser; the arguments of this parser are based on the annotations decorator.  `main` in my test is from the `plac` documentation.

```
In [22]: p=plac.parser_from(main)

In [23]: p
Out[23]: ArgumentParser(prog='ipython2.7', usage=None, description=None, version=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
```

`p.consume` is a longer function, that checks for things like subparsers.  But at some point it does

```
ns, extraopts = self.parse_known_args(arglist)
   # or self.parse_args
```

`ns` is an argparse Namespace, with parameters set by the parser - both defaults and ones from the command line.  It then calls 'the function' with values from `ns` (split into `Python` positional args and keyword args).

So you can call that parser directly:

```
In [25]: p.parse_args([])    # or with the default sys.argv[1:]
Out[25]: Namespace(args=[], kw={}, opt=None)
```

The `p.print_help()` also shows the arguments that it expects from the commandline, but in a neatly formatted form.

And if you want to get further into the `argparse` guts you can look at `p._actions`, a list of `argparse.Action` objects that it uses to parse the commandline.